# sql server error Login failded for user domainname\machinename$

Tags: sql-server

Hi All I have C# desktop application which uses database, we have requirement that connection string should be widows authentication based. Connection string is  'Data Source=ServerName\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;'

We used Set up project to deploy the application. I have added the code in the Installer class to launch the application after finishing the setup as follows

private void MyInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)

```
    {

        try

        {

            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName

            (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

            Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(

              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\ApplicationName.exe");

        }

        catch(Exception ex)

        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }

    }
```

everything works fine on windows XP. But on Windows 7 while launching the application first time after finishing the setup it throws sql exception that 'Login failed for user 'DomainName\WENATEHEE$'' But when I explicitly launch this application from Program Menu it works fine. I have given all required permission to the user. Upon deeper observation I have found that while launching application first time it is log in in the sql server as DomainName\MachineName$ not DomainName\User.

I am not getting any solution on this. any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

The installation process consists of two stages 'Immediate mode' and 'Deferred mode'. The latter one uses 'Windows Installer Service' to execute its scripts as they might need privilege elevation.
For the first time your application is launched in the second phase (earlier mentioned 'Deferred mode') in the context of `LocalSystem` account (as Windows Installer Service runs in the context of this account), because your app is connecting to external system it has to authenticate itself with machine account 'DomainName\WENATEHEE$' (not `LocalSystem` account).
That's why you see  'Login failed for user 'DomainName\WENATEHEE$' error.

Try to add your execution in this method of your class derived from the `Installer`:

```
protected override void OnAfterInstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.OnAfterInstall(savedState);
    // add you app launching code here 
}
```

Comment: I have added the app launching code in onAfterInstall Method but I am getting the same error. Could you please suggest any other option

Thanks, Narendra